# Android emulator sdcard specs

Tags: android-emulator

Questions about using sd-card in android emulator.

1. what is default file system of this file ?
2. Any tool to mount and browse sd-card file on Windows OS ? because the DDMS file browser is very limited, and hides .* files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple actually:

`sudo mount -o loop /test/sdcard.img /mnt/sd`